# Laravel 5.4 - InvalidTransformation in Fractal.php line 348.

Tags: php, laravel-5

As you know, laravel-fractal is one of the greatest package for API development. 
Since today, I'm facing an issue that throws error like the title when i try to deploy the code to remote server. I want you to know, build works perfectly on my local machine.

When i dd the $user in UserTransformer, all properties seem good an it is a User Instance as expected. also i have same problem for categories, news and pages transformers. There is one transformer working but structure is same so i can't figure out what's going on.

Here is my snippets :

UserTransformer.php

```
class UserTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{

    protected $defaultIncludes = ['token'];

    /**
     * A Fractal transformer.
     * @param User $user
     * @return array
     */
    public function transform(User $user)
    {
        return [
            'email' => $user->email,
        ];
    }

    public function includeToken(User $user){
        $token = $user->createToken('Access')->accessToken;
        return $this->item($token,new TokenTransformer());
    }
}
```

TokenTransformer.php

```
class TokenTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    /**
     * A Fractal transformer.
     * @param $token
     * @return array
     */
    public function transform($token)
    {
        return [
            'token' => $token
        ];
    }
}
```

api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return fractal()
        ->item($request->user())
        ->transformWith(new \App\Transformers\Auth\UserTransformer)
        ->toArray();
});
```

Error :

```
InvalidTransformation in Fractal.php line 348:
in Fractal.php line 348
at Fractal->getResource() in Fractal.php line 333
at Fractal->createData() in Fractal.php line 304
at Fractal->toArray() in api.php line 20
at Router->{closure}(object(Request)) in Route.php line 189
```

Maybe I'm missing something, so i'm posting the category transformer too

CategoryTransformer.php

```
class CategoryTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{

    protected $defaultIncludes = ['nodes'];
    protected $availableIncludes = ['pages'];

    /**
     * A Fractal transformer.
     * @param Category $category
     * @return array
     */
    public function transform(Category $category=null)
    {
        if($category){

            return [
                'parent' => $category->parent->slug ?? false,
                'name' => $category->name,
                'slug' => $category->slug,
                'page_count' => $category->pages()->count(),
                'info' => []
            ];
        }

        return [];

    }


    public function includeNodes(Category $category){
        $nodes = $category->children;
        return $this->collection($nodes,new CategoryTransformer,['nodes']);
    }


    public function includePages(Category $category){
        return $this->collection($category->pages,new PageTransformer());
    }
}
```

CategoryController.php

```
public function show(Category $category,Request $request){

    //API

        return fractal()
            ->item($category)
            ->transformWith(new CategoryTransformer())
            ->parseIncludes(['pages','nodes.pages'])
            ->toArray();


}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After digging little bit i see that my locale is tr which capitalized 'i' is 'İ' instead of 'I'
so in Fractal.php line 345

```
$resourceClass = 'League\\Fractal\\Resource\\'.ucfirst($this->dataType);
```

returns `League\Fractal\Resource\item` instead of `League\Fractal\Resource\Item`

i don't know how to fix it without changing src code. But for now i changed locale to en for api routes & controllers and seems fine.